# JQuery JSON parsing / AJAX issue ('remove' and '__proto__' keys in arrays?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I am seeing a strange issue when fetching a JSON object from a URL using Jquery $.ajax function.

I am using the following JQuery call to retrieve the JSON object:

```
1  $.ajax({
2       url: '/test/getjson',
3       success: function(data){
4                     doSomething(data); //(breakpoint here)
5                },
6       error: function(x,y,z){
7                     //error..
8               }
9  });
```

The URL '/test/getjson' returns the following JSON object
(Here is what the response looks like in Firebug):

```
{
    "rsp": {
        "date": "1299195954782" ,
        "type": "Type1" ,
        "Main": {
            "Category1" : {
                "private" : "Y" ,
                "properties" : {
                    "one" : {
                        "response" : "" ,
                        "text" : "label" ,
                        "type" : "property"
                    },
                    "two" : {
                        "options" : [
                            "1" ,
                            "2" ,
                            "3" ,
                            "4" ,
                            "5" ,
                            "6" ,
                            "7" ,
                            "8" ,
                            "9" ,
                            "10"
                        ],
                        "response" : "1" ,
                        "text" : "label2" ,
                        "type" : "property2"
                    }
                }
            },
            "username" : "spiderman"
        }
    }
}
```

### Problem

The problem is that all arrays in the JSON object have extra values with keys 'remove' and '__proto__' after being parsed by JQuery (Firebug's Debugger viewing JSON data object, breakpoint at line 4 in the JS snippet above):

[image]

[JSON object as seen by Firebugs debugger]

And here is a closer look at the strange part of the JSON object:

[image]

[Closer look at the unknown data]

Thanks ahead everyone :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stop using "for ... in" to iterate over arrays, and use an index variable.

```
for (var i = 0; i < theArray.length; ++i) {
  var element = theArray[i];
  // ...
}
```

Those object properties are there thanks to the JavaScript runtime in your browser.  I'm not sure why they'd cause you any trouble because they should not be iterable. Perhaps if you showed the actual code that you've got to process the ajax response, the issue might become more clear.

Comment: @Peter Bailey yes indeed, or Prototype's iteration facilities, or whatever floats the boat :-)

Comment: Man you guys are good; you assumed right that I was traversing these arrays using _for...in's_. I replaced _for...in's_ to regular _for loops_ to iterate over arrays. Thanks